# How can I wait for Stripe to complete payment before I execute a Python function on specific file?

Tags: python, csv, stripe-payments

I am using Python + Flask to build an app that takes a user CSV file and enriches it with data from an API.

My objective:

- User uploads CSV file [done]
- A payment amount is set and presented on Stripe payment page [done]
- Once user pays, then the CSV file is enriched with data from an API (a column is appended), and is emailed to the user. [enriching and emailing is done. I just don't know how to make it wait + match payment to correct csv]

My question:

- How can I make sure that the CSV file is not enriched/emailed to the user until the Stripe payment is completed?

I have set up a webhook. The problem is, I don't know how to match up the CSV file the user uploaded with the actual payment_id from Stripe to make sure I send them the right file.

I'm sure I am just blanking on some concept here, so any directional help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for Stripe to complete a payment before executing a Python function, you'll need to implement a webhook that listens for the `payment_intent.succeeded` event in Stripe. When this event is triggered, it indicates that the payment has been completed successfully, and you can then execute your Python function.

Here's a basic outline of the steps you'll need to take:

1. Implement a webhook endpoint in your application that listens for the `payment_intent.succeeded` event in Stripe.
2. In the webhook endpoint, when the `payment_intent.succeeded` event is triggered, you can call your Python function.
3. Configure the webhook endpoint in your Stripe dashboard to send the `payment_intent.succeeded` event to your application.

Here's a simple example implementation in Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
def webhook():
  # Retrieve the event data from the request
  event_json = request.get_json()

  # Check if the event is a payment_intent.succeeded event
  if event_json["type"] == "payment_intent.succeeded":
    # Call your Python function here
    execute_python_function()

  return "success"

def execute_python_function():
  # Your Python function code goes here
  ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Note that this is just a basic example, and you'll need to modify it to meet the specific needs of your application. You'll also need to ensure that your webhook endpoint is secured and can only be accessed by Stripe.